# How to set imagefield in django model with dynamically set sub directories

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to upload photos to specific directories.

I have below model code.

```
@reversion.register()
    class Student(BaseModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, verbose_name=_("Unique Identifier"), unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("User"))
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="student/", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Photo"))
    std_status = models.IntegerField(choices=STD_STATUS, default=1, verbose_name=_("Stu Sta"))
    std_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name=_("Stu Num"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name=_("Surname"))
```

For the photo line. It uploads photos to **student/** directory. But i need to have subdirectories with User name and dates. Like **"student/jenifer_argon/2019223/2022/07/01"**
I can set **"student/"** directory but username and std_no and date should be dynamically set. **student/user/std_no/date** user and std_no should come from above model on creation runtime.
How can i do this?

It is like; everything will be on same form. But std_no and user will be set first than they will be used to set upload diretory definition and image will be uploaded to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

A function can be passed to [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) that is passed the instance and filename, you can construct your path using these

```
from datetime import date

def student_photo_path(instance, filename):
    today = date.today()
    return 'student/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}'.format(
        instance.user.username,
        instance.std_no,
        today.year,
        today.month,
        today.day,
        filename
    )


class Student(BaseModel):
    ...
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=student_photo_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Photo"))
   ...
```

Comment: Hello, it looks logical but how will i pass instance and filename to student_photo_path function. The file name is handled dynamically by django model form.

Comment: The instance and filename is automatically passed to the function when the model form is saved. If you have some custom logic in your form that changes the filename then please add it to your question

Comment: Oh i didnt know that. Let me try it. Thanks alot.